# How to launch a full-trust process as elevated from UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to launch a full-trust process program from my UWP app. I am using the PackageManager in my full-trust process to locate UWP packages to launch files or links, so I need to run it as an admin.

When I try running the full-trust process, it opens and works properly on my machine (I am running an admin account). However, when I look up the process in the Task Manager, it does not run elevated.

I'm just worried that it may not work on any other machine (non-admin) out there. Here's my code I'm using in Package.appxmanifest, courtesy of Stefan Wick (https://stefanwick.com/2018/10/07/app-elevation-samples-part-3/):

```
<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Assets\NitishTest.exe">
        <desktop:FullTrustProcess>
               <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="Parameters" Parameters="parameters" />
        </desktop:FullTrustProcess>
</desktop:Extension>

<uap3:Extension Category="windows.appExecutionAlias"
                Executable="Assets\NitishTest.exe"
                EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
        <uap3:AppExecutionAlias>
                <desktop:ExecutionAlias Alias="NitishTest.exe" />
        </uap3:AppExecutionAlias>
</uap3:Extension>
```

I am not using a Windows Application Packaging Project, however. Could this be the reason why it's not working properly elevated?

Comment: I have checked above case description, but I could not find you have declared `allowElevation` capability.  You may declare [allowElevation capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities) **which allows app that are created by Microsoft partners and enterprises to preserve existing desktop functionality** that requires auto-elevation on launch or during an app’s lifetime in **Package.appxmanifest**.

Comment: In addition, we suggest you use Windows Application Packaging Project (a new feature) which is introduced on Windows 10, version 1607 to generate a package for your desktop app.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT Hello Yan, thanks for the comment. I actually have declared allowElevation in the manifest below this code snippet. Will this run the full-trust process as administrator?

Comment: Could you please tell me if you have added the code about relaunching the process as admin using the AppExecutionAlias in Program.cs of the "Elevated Extension", as described in the blog of  Stefan Wick?

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT  Hello Yan, I actually did add the code for relaunching as admin and it's working now. Thanks! I'm just having an issue getting PackageManager to work even if the full-trust process is elevated (I have another post).